# cloud function - unable to find module

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am getting below error while deploying `Cloud Function`.

```
Deployment failure:
Function load error: Code in file main.py can't be loaded.
Did you list all required modules in requirements.txt?
Detailed stack trace: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 256, in check_or_load_user_function
    _function_handler.load_user_function()
  File "/env/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/functions/worker.py", line 166, in load_user_function
    spec.loader.exec_module(main)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/user_code/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

This is how my packaged zip structure looks like:

```
.
├── main.py
└── requirements.txt
```

This is how my requirements.txt looks like:

```
beautifulsoup4==4.7.1
boto3==1.9.75
botocore==1.12.75
cachetools==3.0.0
certifi==2018.11.29
chardet==3.0.4
docutils==0.14
google-api-core==1.7.0
google-auth==1.6.2
google-cloud-core==0.29.1
google-cloud-datastore==1.7.3
google-resumable-media==0.3.2
googleapis-common-protos==1.5.5
grpcio==1.17.1
idna==2.8
jmespath==0.9.3
protobuf==3.6.1
pyasn1==0.4.5
pyasn1-modules==0.2.3
python-dateutil==2.7.5
pytz==2018.9
requests==2.21.0
rsa==4.0
s3transfer==0.1.13
six==1.12.0
soupsieve==1.6.2
urllib3==1.24.1
```

This is how I am importing `bs4` module in `main.py`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from datetime import datetime
import boto3
import re
```

According to [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/python-runtime#source_code_structure), requirements.txt file must be in the same directory as the main.py file that contains your function code. which you can see that it is.

Please note that this is working fine from my local system.

Service account attached to the function has below roles:

```
Cloud Datastore User
Storage Admin
```

When I go to Cloud Functions UI from the console. I can see main.py and requirements.txt both are showing up there with the right content in the `source` tab.

What am I missing here?

### Update

Figured out the problem. If I mention `beautifulsoup4==4.7.1` in requirements.txt file, it fails. But if I do not specify version number in there, it works. `beautifulsoup4`

Not sure why though. Any idea?

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the deployment issue with `beautifulsoup4==4.7.1`, is it possible you didn't have the file saved with the added dependency before you deployed?

Comment: No. I verified it and manually edited requirements.txt file multiple times. I am using python 3.7 environment. May be that’s the issue?

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce it even with your exact `requirements.txt` file. I am using the Python 3.7 environment as well.

Comment: I was using `lxml` (e.g. `BeautifulSoup(body, "lxml")`) and my CF (cloud function) was failing silently. After I added `lxml` to `requirements.txt` the CF started working again.

Answer (score 1):

In my case when I defined soup as:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, features="xml")
```

It ran into an error when calling soup (saying soup was not defined). Adding lxml to my `requirements.txt` fixed the problem.